# This site can’t be reached [flask, python]

Tags: python, google-chrome, flask

when I open the link 0.0.0.0:5000 in my browser I always get the message on the browser "This site can't be reached"
the code seems to be working since I get this message on the console

> Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

[image]

here is the code that I am using

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from scipy.misc import imsave, imread, imresize
import numpy as np
import keras.models
import re
import sys
import os
from load import *

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('./model'))
app = Flask(__name__)
global model, graph
model, graph = init()

def convertImage(imData):
    imgstr = re.search(r'base64(.*'.imData).group(1)
    with open('output.png', 'wb') as output:
        output.write(imgstr.decode('base64'))

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    imData = request.get_data()
    convertImage(imData)
    x = imread('output.png', mode = 'L')
    x = np.invert(x)
    x = imresize(x, 48, 48)
    x = x.reshape(1,48,48,1)
    with graph.as_default():
        out = model.predict(x)
        response = np.array_str(np.argmax(out))
        return response



if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address, so you can't actually connect to it. When the server says it's "runinng on 0.0.0.0" it means it is accepting connections on any network adapter, not a specific one. Use 127.0.0.1 to actually connect to a server running on your machine.

Comment: I tried that actually and it is not working, it was working before using 0.0.0.0:5000 but now I don't know what is the problem

Comment: @kindall I found the solution and your comment really helped, I changed the host to 127.0.0.1 but what I forgot is that flask looks for the index.html file in the templates folder and I did not put it there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, this message

> Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

informs you about the IP-address of your PC that will be listened to accept the request. It can be configured to listen to only one IP-address.

As it has been stated in the comments, if you are trying to reach your Web site from the same PC you develop on, you may use virtual (loop) address `127.0.0.1`. In case you want to check how your Web site will look on your other devices that are connected to the same network (i.e. tablet, phone, other PC whatever else), you need to type your PC's internal network IP address, and it differs from the loop. It may be e.g. 192.168.1.1 (you should check it on your NIC properties). And it may changes if you try to make something like live-demo to your friends.

So in order, to prevent you from checking each time, which one IP-address is valid for your PC right now, you can use `0.0.0.0` telling to your application 'listen for incoming requests from ALL the NICs, whatever IP-address they have'.

Comment: Is there any reason why `0.0.0.0` would not work when `127.0.0.1` does work? Doesn't `0.0.0.0` just listen for strictly *more*?

Comment: Would not work where? If you try to reach `0.0.0.0` - there is no such IP in your network. If you want to bind something to `0.0.0.0` and it doesn't work, this case must be investigated, right now I cannot imagine any option why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 5):

For me using `app.run(debug=False)` worked when using

```
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

did not.

I can't tell if this is a firewall issue or why it didn't work. Do note that after doing this it started hosting at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`.

Answer (score 2):

Both http://127.0.0.1:5000 and http://localhost:5000 are correct
use it instead of 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

definitely use, ur local host with 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

To test locally, instead of http://0.0.0.0:5000, you can use http://localhost:5000

Answer (score 0):

For me using `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0`

like this:

```
 app.run(host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Always run docker in detached mode, in my case I tried running docker in detached mode and it worked. As we want to access the URL in browser. i.e. outside the container, The best solution is to run in detached mode and by exposing the port.

```
 docker run -d -p 5000:5000 flask_docker_practise
```

Above we are passing -d to run container in detached mode and then we pass -p to let the container know on which port we want to expose and listen.